# What does this Do While Loop code do?

Tags: vb.net

I'm very new to Visual Basic and I'm having a hard time understanding "Do While" loops. The code I'm struggling with is below. Can someone walk me through what the code is doing? I understand the variables and assigning the label, I'm just not sure how to translate the loop.

```
Dim intSum As Integer
Dim intY As Integer

Do While intY < 3
  For intX As Integer = 1 To 4
  Next intX

  intY += 1
Loop

lblSum.Text = intSum.ToString
```

Comment: There are loops but they don't do anything... I would highly suggest you learn how to step through your code, it would tell you exactly what it's doing.

Comment: The Do loop increments intY by one each time, and also runs the For loop again each time. The For loop does nothing useful at all, because there's no code in it. That's all. Neither of them do anything interesting really. To see for yourself, run it in Visual Studio, set breakpoints (or set your code to break on every line) and step through the code to understand the flow of execution - by doing that you can also see the values of your variables at each stage of the program. If you fundamentally don't understand how loops work, it might be worth studying some introductory tutorials etc.

Comment: Nothing besides looping around four times... The for loop does the same thing but each time for the do loop.

Comment: and, the intY ought to be set prior to entry in the loop.

Comment: @strobelight, it is by default at 0 in vb, c# is a different story...

Comment: yes I know, but a good understanding of `do` vs `for` would show `intY` would only be incremented once if it's value is 3 or more. `do` runs at least once before criteria checked.

Comment: @strobelight "do runs at least once before criteria checked" - this is wrong with the Do While loop shown.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the example has simply been extracted from a larger program and the interesting bits of what the For loop and other stuff inside the While loop have been removed.

A Do While loop coded this way is similar to coding a For loop like:

```
For intY = 0 to 3
Next
```

But without actually specifying the starting condition for intY.  It starts out as whatever value it has coming into the loop, which is sometimes handy.

The example doesn't modify intSum in any way, but I'm guessing that part of the code is just not included here.